# GWT request payload understanding

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

If you look below is my payload going to server when I made a RPC call in my application

> `7|0|14|http://domain.com/ager-online/tracklay/|7FCCBC6F7B44BB2BEB84AAB8B47DB2E4|com.d.g4.consumer.w.client.rpcservice.ConsumerService|placeService|java.util.List|java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|co.g.consumer.wager.client.model.ConsumernseType/2494043886|java.lang.Double/858496421|java.lang.Integer/3438268394|2|1|WIN|java.lang.Long/4227064769|java.util.Date/3385151746|1|2|3|4|1|5|6|1|7|8|2|8|2|9|1|10|11|11|12|13|Co3|14|**Uzc1OKs**|9|309158|-5|`

I know its being serialized and sending data to server. What I want to know is the keys in middle. like **Uzc1OKs** I marked them in the request.

What exactly they are ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please add the method signature of the remote procedure you are calling.

Comment: Have *you* done any research before asking this question? GWT is open source and it should be pretty easy to track down the "culprit" - check the classes generated from your `*Async` interfaces by the GWT compiler, see what classes are used there and follow the trail till you find the serialization scheme. Or google around...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this open-source tool?
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-payload-deserializer/

Here is payload elements explanation:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-payload-deserializer/wiki/GwtPayloadDefinition

Answer (score 1):

You can use GWT [RPC](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) in the following way on the client:

Creating a service

```
private void refreshWatchList() {
    final double MAX_PRICE = 100.0; // $100.00
    final double MAX_PRICE_CHANGE = 0.02; // +/- 2%

    StockPrice[] prices = new StockPrice[stocks.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stocks.size(); i++) {
      double price = Random.nextDouble() * MAX_PRICE;
      double change = price * MAX_PRICE_CHANGE
          * (Random.nextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0);

      prices[i] = new StockPrice(stocks.get(i), price, change);
    }

    updateTable(prices);
  }
```

Defining the service

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")
public interface StockPriceService extends RemoteService {

      StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols);
}
```

Implementing the service

```
public class StockPriceServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements StockPriceService {

    public StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Invoking the service from the client and making the remote procedure call:

```
private ArrayList<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();
private StockPriceServiceAsync stockPriceSvc = GWT.create(StockPriceService.class);

private void refreshWatchList() {
    // Initialize the service proxy.
    if (stockPriceSvc == null) {
      stockPriceSvc = GWT.create(StockPriceService.class);
    }

     // Set up the callback object.
    AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]>() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO: Do something with errors.
      }

      public void onSuccess(StockPrice[] result) {
        updateTable(result);
      }
    };

     // Make the call to the stock price service.
    stockPriceSvc.getPrices(stocks.toArray(new String[0]), callback);
}
```

This is basically what RPC is done.

Your

> keys in middle

is probably the result of serialization your objects. If you don't like that you can also use the GWT `RequestBuilder`.

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(requestMethod, url); 
requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
requestBuilder.setRequestData(bodyString);
requestBuilder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

      @Override
      public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        callback.onResponse(response.getStatusCode(), response.getText());
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        callback.onError(new Exception(exception));
      }
    });

    try {
      requestBuilder.send();
    }
    catch(RequestException ex) {
      callback.onError(ex);
    }
```

When using RequestBuilder you have more control of the format and what is being transported.

Answer (score -1):

GWT uses Protocol Buffers as a serialization mechanism by default. You can find more here: [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: GWT **does not use protocol buffers** for its RPC implementation!  However, there has been some discussion on this topic (see https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/2655 for example)